# Moving points to nearest raster cell with values in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, point

I have two types of data, one that is a point vector (occurrences), and one that is a raster (environment). The environmental data has both cells with numerical values or NA. Both of the types of data have the wgs84 coordinate system.

Due to the coarse scale of the environmental data, some of the occurrences fall just outside of the environmental cells with values and instead are within the cells with NA.

I want to be able to shift the geographic location of the occurrences from the cells with NA to the nearest cell with numerical values.

I want to shift them geographically, and not just sample the value of the nearest cell, because I am uploading the data into another program that builds a model based on the association between where the occurrences are and the environmental data they fall within.

How do I do this in ArcMap?

Comment: How big is your raster, rows and columns?

Comment: There are 27 rows and 52 columns.

Comment: Convert your raster to points. Run near tool with location between sampling points and points from raster. Use arcpy.Point(near_x,near_y) on field Shape of selected sampling points. This will move them to centre of nearest cell.

Comment: In environment setting set snap raster.

Comment: @FelixIP, given small raster size, I think that’s the answer.

Comment: @FelixIP It worked, thank you!